# Virtual hosting in lighttpd?

Tags: hosting, lighttpd, virtualization

Ok, here it goes... I've seen some other posts dealing with this, but it didn't help that much. I am using Windows XP. My problem is with trying to get lighttpd working with virtual hosts. Now, I managed to get everything up and working with the default `/htdocs` and the default page shows up just fine on the internet, but since I have several sites to host, I need virtual hosting. I managed to do it in apache, so I guessed it would work out just fine in lighttpd, but apparently I'm missing something.

Ok, let's say I have domain `(www.)example.org`. I want everyone using that url going to the correct `index.html`, obviously. Let's say that index.html is in directory `websites/website1` placed under the lighttpd dir. (thus, the full path is `c:/ProgramsFiles/lighttpd/websites/website1/index.html`)

Now: How, exactly, do I set up my virtual host (in the config file)? In detail, please, since I've tried for hours with the vague hints I got from fora and such, but it doesn't work.

Also is there something additional to do? Change the `server.bind` or get rid of the default `server.document-root`, or something?

I appreciate all the help you can give! Especially if it's a verbatim/step-by-step solution you're offering!

Edit: And, yes, my `mod_simple_vhost` has been enabled.

Comment: Maybe you can include what you configurations look like at the moment?

Answer (score 3):

All you'll need is a config like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|www\.)example\.org$" {
    server.document-root = "C:/Program Files/lighttpd/websites/website1/" 
}
```

Not quite sure how the path needs to be formatted under Windows - maybe escape the space in `Program Files`?

You don't need `mod_simple_vhost` unless you're looking to have dynamically configured vhosts based on the domain name.

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thanks a lot! I'm not sure why it isn't mentioned anywhere in the ## explanation in the config file like that. I don't think I would have ever found it, with the $HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|www\.)example\.org$" { -thingy; I just kept trying it the way it was indicated in the ##part of the configfile. Must have tried dozens of variants, to no avail. But anyway, this worked like a charm! Thnks again!